# XML object changes itself between requests

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an XML object

```
running_config = <data>
    <configuration xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/xnm/1.1/xnm">
      .
      .
    </configuration>
</data>
```

> The following code works:

```
rc = self.running_config.find('//config:configuration', namespaces=namespace)
```

> And I can get result:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/xnm/1.1/xnm"> .. 
</configuration>` 
<br>***Response received on the client***
```

But only for the first time
When the same request is received again, I observe that `running_config` object is reduced to `<data> </data>` (there is no `<configuration>` element present anymore) 
 
and hence, `rc = self.running_config.find('//config:configuration', namespaces=namespace)` returns `None`

> Here is my code snippet:

```
rc = self.running_config.find('//config:configuration', namespaces=namespace)
# check if response is expected in json/xml
root = etree.ElementTree(rpc)
config = root.find('//get-configuration', namespaces=namespace)
if 'format' in config.attrib:
    if config.attrib['format'] == 'xml':
        print 'sending xml response'
        return rc 
#send response in json
```

I am unable to understand what is happening here.

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: @mzjn I don't know what is causing this behavior, hence I can not say how to reproduce this.

Comment: I understand that you don't know what causes the behaviour, but it is hard to help without a [mcve].